# Why do I get the sql server error "column is invalid"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the code below:

```
select vend_id, COUNT(vend_id) as num_prods
from Products
group by vend_id
```

When I remove the last line, I get the following error:

> Column 'Products.vend_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Why do I get this error? What is the mistake I am making (in understanding how count works)?

Comment: Please tell me how exactly count() works. Maybe my conceptual understanding is wrong.

Comment: I think you got it right. Make sure the columns are spelled correctly.

Comment: not able to understand count properly. I was not trying to get a result,but just following the example in my book.

Answer (score 2):

Count is an aggregate function.

It returns the number of items in the set defined by your query.

If there are no columns in your query, count will just count the total number of rows returned by the query.

If you add other columns to the select list, you will need to add a group by statement to give meaning to count.  Group by tells the aggregate functions to operate on all of the rows that have the same value for the columns in the group by statement.

The query you gave in your question would return a list of unique vend_id values and the number of times that those values exist in the given table.  If the vend_id column is a unique key on that table, then you will just get a list of vend_id and 1 for each row.

Please see this document for detailed explanation of the COUNT function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997(v=sql.105).aspx

See this document for explanation of aggregate functions, in general:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This is what i see in the 1st link you gave. I noticed the word group in the explanations. So, count without group by is meaningless, right ?

COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL values and duplicates.

COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of nonnull values.

COUNT(DISTINCT expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of unique, nonnull values.

Comment: Yes.  That is exactly how it works.  Any further questions, or does that clear it up for you?

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative way of writing the query without using Group By:**

```
select vend_id, (select COUNT(*) from Products as products1 where products1.vend_id = Products.vend_id) as num_prods
from Products
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure it won't do anything different.

Comment: @zneak yes, I agree, it will give same result.

Comment: No, i get a different result. much different.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because when you remove the last line from your query, you are selecting vend_id in both an aggregate function `count(vend_id)` and a non-aggregate function `vend_id`. You are asking for one totaled column (the count one) and one detail one (without the count). You need to tell SQL Server what to do with any of the non-totaled columns.

```
select vend_id
from Products

select count(vend_id)
from Products
```

Both of the queries above are valid. If you want to select vend_id and count by it as well, you have to group by it.

Comment: Are you saying the count without having group by is meaningless ?

Comment: No, just different. Counting all vend_id's in your table give you a grand total. Counting vend_id's while selecting and grouping by vend_id gives you a count of each different vend_id in your table.